# Frameless shower door side sweep

Tags: shower

I've been trying to find a replacement for this side door sweep for a while with no luck. It looks like it was glued on rather than using one of the thicker plastic friction ones? I have had no difficulty finding the bottom sweep, but this one has been more difficult. Do I just need to find a longer friction one for the side sweep?[image][image]

Comment: I cant tell, whats what. Have you trued going to a shower place and asking them for it?